# Passing dropdown values to HttpGet api in Angular

Tags: angular

I am very much new to Angular 10 .  I have a text file that has the following Product ID's

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

So I want to display these values in a drop down box. Once the values are displayed I want to take a single value and send this value to my HTTPGet api method which will display  the list of product names below the dropdown box.

Any sample code will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering why are the values coming from a text file.
It's better to create a javascript array from them.

`const productIds = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`

If you want just a dropdown, I understand that this is a simple select?
If you don't have a ui library yet maybe you can take a look to material design, how you can use a select. https://material.angular.io/components/select/examples

Comment: Actually its a requirement that it needs to be in a text file

Comment: And the text file is served from where? From a backend?
In that case you will need to split on lines

Comment: The Text file is in the root folder

Answer (score 0):

Better to move the text file into /assets folder.

here is an example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ryazly?file=src%2Fapp%2Fselect-overview-example.ts

Then you need to pass the selected product id to your HTTP get request.